# laravel 5.1 Create a table row with migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, database-migration

I have a question regarding Migrations in Laravel. I have a webapp where only an administrator can create a user, but when first launching the webapp from 0 I have no users and since only and admin can create users in the admin section which is guarded with a password I can't do anything on the webpage.

The question is, when I create I migration, can I create a user with in?

I would do it manually in my DB, but the password is hashed with bcrypt.

If I cant do it with migrations, would you have any other suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use seeders to create the admin user. This is a [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding) on how to create seeder files

Comment: This may not be a good idea if the OP wants to make a permanent production user, and uses seeds for temporary data. Permanent, production data should go in separate migrations, IMO.